# CORDA blockchain storage options

Tags: corda

I am new to CORDA blockchain, and i would like to know the possibilities of Storing the corda states/vault in NoSQL DBs like Elasticsearch or Cassandra. Or can we put the vault data to ActiveMQ?

Answer (score 0):

Supported databases:

- **Open Source Edition:** H2, PostgreSQL, and SQL Server (untested).
  Source: https://docs.corda.net/node-database.html
- **Enterprise Edition:** Azure SQL, SQL Server, Oracle, and PostgreSQL.
  Source: https://docs.corda.r3.com/node-database.html#node-database